# Boost shared pointer publishing - zero copy

Tags: ros, roscpp, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Community,

I have read that the intra process communication can be done by publishing message using boost shared pointer of the message. Then there is zero copy. Apparentely this is what makes nodelets so powerful.

1. My question now, is this valid only
   for nodelets that we should publish
   using pointers and there is zero
   copy ? Is this also true between different
   nodes ?
2. Also is there a requirement that the nodelets be launched from the same nodelet manager for the zero copy to be true ?
3. Is there a way to check/test whether there is zero copy happening in my implementation or my code is using network resources ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248365/boost-shared-pointer-publishing---zero-copy/) by [ROSfc](https://answers.ros.org/users/27827/rosfc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 54 on 2016-11-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> 1 . My question now, is this valid only for nodelets that we should publish using pointers and there is zero copy ? Is this also true between different nodes ?

No, only nodelets can exchange pointers*, as they share the same address space (they're basically nodes mapped onto threads instead of processes)

(* this is not entirely true: with a suitable transport (such as [ethzasl_message_transport](http://wiki.ros.org/ethzasl_message_transport)) zero-copy msg exchange is also possible between nodes, but that is not out-of-the-box supported and comes with some constraints)

> 2 . Also is there a requirement that the nodelets be launched from the same nodelet manager for the zero copy to be true ?

yes, again because they need to share an address space. Different managers will each have their own address spaces.

> 3 . Is there a way to check/test whether there is zero copy happening in my implementation or my code is using network resources ?

I know of no other way than checking resource usage (ie: CPU / memory). But in most contexts where nodelets make sense, the increase in performance is so noticeable that you'll know when it's not working (this is obviously not a good way to check, but is at least something).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jespestana](https://answers.ros.org/users/4328/jespestana/) on 2019-02-13**:
Thanks for the in-depth answer!

I have a follow-up comment/question about question 3: would it not be possible to check that the zero-copy has taken place by checking for equality the addresses to which the message pointers are pointing to (on the side of the publisher and each subscriber)?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-13**:
Yes, theoreticall this should be possible. I'm not entirely sure (any more, it's been a while) whether there is no place in the control flow between publisher and subscriber (in `nodelet`) that potentially alters the address.

But in principle the pointers should be equal.

**Comment by [jespestana](https://answers.ros.org/users/4328/jespestana/) on 2019-02-13**:
I think so too. Thanks.

Actually, I just checked it. And yes, you get the same address on both sides of the message transport (subscriber and publisher).